Space between banner image and rest of page HTML CSS
I am encountering an issue where my banner image has a blank space before displaying the rest of the page. I have no padding for the header and cannot figure out why this is happening



.background {
  position: relative;
  width: 99vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  &::before {
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    align-self: center;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    background-image: url(../images/jeeves_and_wooster_itv.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-size: cover;
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
}

header {
  position: relative;
}

header nav {
  position: absolute;
  left: 250px;
  top: 200px;
}

nav a {
  color: rgb(70, 70, 70);
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 32px;
}

#banner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

main {
  position: relative;
  align-self: center;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: auto;
  height: 90%;
  width: 90%;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

footer {
  background-color: burlywood;
  padding: 15px;
  display: flex;
}

footer .left {
  float: left;
}

footer .right {
  float: right;
  margin: auto;
}

h1 {
  font-family: "Playfair Display", "Times New Roman", serif;
}

p {
  font-family: "Source Sans 3", Arial, sans-serif;
}
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css" type="text/css">
  <link rel="icon" href="images/logo.png" type="image/jpg" sizes="16x16">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav>
      <a href="index.html">Home</a>
      <a href="characters.html">Characters</a>
      <a href="books.html">Books</a>
      <a href="tv.html">TV Series</a>
    </nav>
    <img src="images/banner2.jpg" alt="World of Wooster" id="banner">
  </header>
  <div class="background">
    <main>
      <p></p>
    </main>


  </div>
  <footer>
    <p class="left">All images remain the property of the original artists.</p>
    <a href="report.html" class="right">Report a problem</a>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>



When inspecting the page with chrome I can see that the header is larger than the banner image even though I have no padding for the header. When manually setting the height of the header to the size of the image it displays correctly but this does not work for different screen sizes.

By default <img> tag is display: inline, which creates a new line if the next tag/container is on the next line. A common solution is to change it to display: block. Giving #banner { display: block; } should solve this issue.
